# C#: Creating an onclicklister to dynamically created button array

Tags: c#, android

I created an array of buttons dynamically with the number of buttons depending on the length of a word. However, I'm having trouble adding an onclicklistener to each button in the array. The following code generates an error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. What I want to do is to remove the text from the button when it is clicked. Also, the width of the button can't be changed to the 50 the I set.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and C# to create an Android app.

```
   private void create_ans_btns(string newWord)
    {            
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.linearLayout);
        Button[] ans_btn = new Button[newWord.Length];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < newWord.Length; counter++)
        {
            ans_btn[counter] = new Button(this);
            ans_btn[counter].Id = counter;
            ans_btn[counter].Text = "" + counter;
            ans_btn[counter].SetHeight(50);
            ans_btn[counter].SetWidth(50);
            ll.AddView(ans_btn[counter]);

            /*
            ans_btn[counter].Click += delegate { ans_btn[counter].Text = ""; };
            */
        }            
    }
```

Comment: How does the `Button[]` define? Cant you try using `List<Button>`, instead of array?

Comment: Try to assign the counter variable to a new variable and use the new variable in the delegate.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: what environment are you working with

Comment: Environment? Not sure how to answer that. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.